# HTML div adjustable

Tags: html, css

One div is fixed size id is post_picture
and one is adjustable id post_text
the problem is the adjustable div id post_text not working well.
my question is how I set that it can work correctly.

```
HTML code:
<div id= "post_body">
    <div id="post_picture">

    </div>
    <div id="post_text">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#post_body
{
    width: 99%;
    height: 81%;
    margin: 4px 1px 2px 3px;
}

#post_picture
{
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    float: left;
    background-color:Silver;
    border-radius:0.4em;
}

#post_text
{
    width: 80.6%;
    max-width: 80.6%;
    min-width: 300px;    
    height: 130px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem(what you are excepting and what happens)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to move post_text outside post_body

```
<div id= "post_body">
                    <div id="post_picture">

                    </div>

                </div>
 <div id="post_text">

                    </div>
```